# SQL Server : a strange thing happens with an Update inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 that the code inside is something like this :

```
select Unique_ID as ID
into tmp_table 
from table1
```

Then, after some other statements, I do this update :

```
Update table1 
set Flag = ‘Y’
Where Unique_ID in (select Unique_ID from tmp_table)
```

As you notice, I've purposely mistaken `ID` by `Unique_ID` (the column name in `tmp_table`) when I wanted to update.

Now the bizarre thing that happens, is that SQL Server doesn’t show an error when I execute the stored procedure.

It ignores the line where the error is :

```
Where Unique_ID in (select Unique_ID from tmp_table)
```

And runs just this :

```
Update table1 set
Flag = ‘Y’
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**:

Here is the stored procedure code :

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @date VARCHAR(20)

    SET @date = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETUTCDATE(), 3), '/', '')
            + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETUTCDATE(), 108), ':', '')

    DECLARE @PATH AS VARCHAR(500)
    SET @PATH = 'C:\MyPath\' 

    BEGIN TRY
            EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @PATH
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT 'FOLDER NOT CREATED'
    END CATCH

    IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'TMP_TABLE')
       DROP TABLE TMP_TABLE

    SELECT  
        UNIQUE_ID [Unique ID] ,
        'col1' COL1,
        'col2' COL2,
        'col3' COL3,
        'col4' COL4
    INTO    
        TMP_TABLE
    FROM    
        TABLE1
    WHERE 
        Flag IN 'N'

    --Try to generate file, If there was any problem, return from the SP => no update
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @QUERY = 'EXEC master..xp_cmdshell ''sqlcmd -E -s"," -W -h-1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT * FROM dbo.TMP_TABLE" | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > '
            + @PaTH + '\FileName_' + @date + '.csv'',no_output;'

        EXEC(@QUERY)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'Exception during file generation'
        RETURN
    END CATCH

    PRINT 'File Generated'

    UPDATE TABLE1 
    SET Flag = 'Y',
        MODIFICATION_DATE = GETDATE()
    WHERE 
        UNIQUE_ID IN (SELECT UNIQUE_ID FROM TMP_TABLE)

    BEGIN TRY
        DROP TABLE dbo.TMP_TABLE
        PRINT 'TMP table dropped'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'TMP table not dropped'
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

The problem is on this line:

```
WHERE UNIQUE_ID IN (SELECT **UNIQUE_ID** FROM TMP_TABLE)
```

I should replace `UNIQUE_ID` with `[UNIQUE ID]`

But SQL Server doesn't throw an error, it simply updates all records.

And here is the structure of table1 :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1]
(
    UNIQUE_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), --Primary key
    Flag [varchar] (1) ,
    MODIFICATION_DATE datetime,
)
```

Comment: Please give the structure of `table1`, because I don't get the behavior that you described. I do run a later version of SQL SERVER, but I cannot see how that can work at all

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the behaviour on SQL SERVER 2005 either...

Comment: is there any field named ID  in your table ???

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to examine the execution of your stored procedure line by line. In your explanation you've missed something. Once you find the answer you'll kick yourself.

Comment: Hi guys I updated my post for more clarifications

Comment: [Qualifying column names in subqueries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178050(v=sql.105).aspx): "If a column is referenced in a subquery that does not exist in the table referenced by the subquery's FROM clause, but exists in a table referenced by the outer query's FROM clause, the query executes without error. SQL Server implicitly qualifies the column in the subquery with the table name in the outer query."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yes you are right.
That was the problem.
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you had a typo in your query. Your tables look like that?

```
create table1 
( Unique_ID int  
, Flag char(1)
, ...
);

create tmp_table
( [Unique ID] int primary key
, ...
);
```

in that case your query is:

```
Update table1 t1 set
Flag = ‘Y’
Where t1.Unique_ID in (select t1.Unique_ID from tmp_table)
```

which is true except your id is null. you just compare the Unique_ID from table1 with itself.

Comment: @yosboss i changed my answer a little bit. the important part is still the same, you compare your table1's ID with itself. thats not wrong but nothing else than table1.Unique_ID=table1.Unique_ID

Comment: @A._Led
yes you are right.
That was the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly refer to the column to which you want to compare, by using the table name as well:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET Flag = 'Y',
    MODIFICATION_DATE = GETDATE()
WHERE 
    UNIQUE_ID IN (SELECT TMP_TABLE.UNIQUE_ID FROM TMP_TABLE)
```

Confusion arises because there's a column named `UNIQUE_ID` on both tables, so by fully-qualifying it with the table name in the subselect, you can be 100% sure that you are referring to the right column.